# Passing a range object from VBA to .NET causes "Runtime Error 91"

Tags: .net, vba, range, excel-interop

Is the .NET type of:
`Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range`
the same type as VBA:
`excel.range`
?

Passing it from VBA to .NET does not work.

It causes:

> Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set.

The .NET code (VB.NET in this case) is:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class clsDotNetClass

private mRangeObject as Excel.Range

Public Property FirstProperty As Excel.Range

        Get
            Return mRangeObject

        End Get

        Set(value As Excel.Range)

            mRangeObject = value

        End Set

    End Property

End class
```

The VBA is:

```
Public sub DoesNotWork ()

Dim wkbObject As Workbook
Dim shtObject As Worksheet
Dim rngObject As Range

Set wkbObject = ThisWorkbook
Set shtObject = wkbObject.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set rngObject = shtObject.Range("A1:B2")

Dim clsAttempt1 as new clsDotNetClass 

With clsAttempt1

    .FirstProperty = rngObject

End With

End sub
```

The COM connection works fine otherwise.

Would appreciate any ideas,

Hein

Comment: You might want to read up about the [General Naming Conventions in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/general-naming-conventions), particularly the part about "Hungarian Notation".

Comment: Also FWIW `As New` is a bad idea in general, but more particularly so when .NET types are involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the .NET type of: `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range` the same type as VBA: `Excel.Range`?

No, it's not. The .NET type is a managed type, the VBA type is a COM object type. The COM-Interop type is wrapping a COM object, making the unmanaged object available through .NET.

Still, the managed interop type should marshal to & from one & the other perfectly fine.

Except this isn't doing what you think it does:

> ```
> With clsAttempt1
>
>     .FirstProperty = rngObject
>
> End With
> ```

Without involving any .NET code, it's the same thing as this:

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim foo As Range
    foo = Sheet1.Range("A1")
End Sub
```

And this code gets flagged by [Rubberduck](http://www.github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck) as follows:

> *Assignment to 'foo' implicitly assigns to the default member '_Default' of class 'EXCEL.EXE:Excel.Range'.*

In other words, you're not assigning `.FirstProperty`, but to `.FirstProperty.[_Default]` (that's documented as "let-coercion" in the VBA specs, here involving a *hidden* default member), and if the range reference hasn't been set then that would be raising error 91, since you're making an implicit member call against `Nothing`.

Try using the `Set` keyword:

```
With clsAttempt1

    Set .FirstProperty = rngObject

End With
```

The `Set` keyword is **required** in VBA, whenever you mean to assign an object reference: this is because in VBA, parameterless default members are perfectly legal (they're not in VB.NET).